# Compare two columns of table a to a single column of table b

Tags: sql, oracle, join, oracle11g

This is in Oracle 11g
I have a table: LOG, which contains among many columns, 2 columns as per below:

```
ticketid
comments
```

I have another table APP_ACCESS which contains (among other columns)

```
user_id
appl_id
env_id
ticketid
```

The user_id, appl_id and env_id of APP_ACCESS are parts of the comments column in the LOG table. Wherever such parts exist (all three), I need to get the ticketid from the LOG table and update APP_ACCESS.

What I tried is below (I am failing at retrieving the ticketid itself, nothing is returned):

```
select L.ticketid from LOG L join APP_ACCESS U
on INSTR(L.COMMENTS, U.USER_ID) > 0 and INSTR(L.COMMENTS, U.APPL_ID) > 0
```

**Edit #1**
Sample data in comments column (Note: this is one cell, that is one column, one row worth of data):

```
ATTEMPTED: MANAGERCOMMENTS="TEST",AFTER: MANAGERCOMMENTS="TEST"
ATTEMPTED: JUSTIFICATION="TEST",AFTER: JUSTIFICATION="TEST"
ATTEMPTED: REQUESTORDIVISION="DOF",AFTER: REQUESTORDIVISION="DOF"
ATTEMPTED: USERSELECTED="VEXUSERTEST",AFTER: USERSELECTED="VEXUSERTEST"
ATTEMPTED: REQUESTTYPE="CHANGE ACCESS",AFTER: REQUESTTYPE="CHANGE ACCESS"
ATTEMPTED: REQUESTORREGION="WASHINGTON",AFTER: REQUESTORREGION="WASHINGTON"
ATTEMPTED: ENVIRONMENTSELECTED="DEVELOPMENT",AFTER: ENVIRONMENTSELECTED="DEVELOPMENT"
ATTEMPTED: REQUESTORCOMMENTS="TEST",AFTER: REQUESTORCOMMENTS="TEST"
ATTEMPTED: APPLICATIONSELECTED="TEST_APP",AFTER: APPLICATIONSELECTED="TEST_APP"
ATTEMPTED: REQUESTOR="PRTEST",AFTER: REQUESTOR="PRTEST"
ATTEMPTED: ADDEDACCESSLEVELS="DEFAULT ACCESS",AFTER: ADDEDACCESSLEVELS="DEFAULT ACCESS"
```

The string after USERSELECTED=" is the same as the USER_ID in the APP_ACCESS table.
The string after APPLICATIONSELECTED=" is the same as the APPL_ID in the APP_ACCESS table. Similarly the string after ENVIRONMENTSELECTED=" is mapped to the ENV_ID in the APP_ACCESS table.

Comment: Can you post a sample `Comments` value with its matching `user_id`, `appl_id` and `env_id` values? `INSTR` can be inaccurate - for example if you're looking for `user_id=10` it'll return a hit when matched against `user_id=10`, `user_id=101`, `user_id=1000`, and so forth. Knowing what the `comments` value looks like will determine if it's possible to work around this.

Comment: @EdGibbs I agree. If the values were delimited or grouped in a known order you would be able scan for those substrings easier.

Comment: I have updated the question with a sample of the comments data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query fails probably because the values in the APP_ACCESS table are surrounded with white space characters or because these values are not fully in upper case. If so, the below query must solve the problem:

```
select L.ticketid from LOG L join APP_ACCESS U
on INSTR(L.COMMENTS, UPPER(TRIM(U.USER_ID))) > 0 
and INSTR(L.COMMENTS, UPPER(TRIM(U.APPL_ID))) > 0
```

other possibilities:

- some middle letters missing; so, the values are similar bot not quite match.
- `ticketid` column is `null`!
- ...

Comment: Thanks! This helped, the UPPER was what clinched it.

Answer (score 1):

Anoop, I'm sorry about the late reply - I didn't see your updated post until a few minutes ago.

I'm not 100% sure how your completed query will look, but as for comparing between the `Log` and `App_Access` tables, the logic will go like this:

```
 INSTR(L.Comments, 'USERSELECTED="' || U.User_ID || '"') > 0 AND
 INSTR(L.Comments, 'APPLICATIONSELECTED="' || U.Appl_ID || '"') > 0 AND
 INSTR(L.Comments, 'ENVIRONMENTSELECTED="' || U.Env_ID || '"') > 0
```

Depending on your needs you could use this in the `WHERE` clause or as part of your `JOIN` conditions. I hope this is enough to move you forward.

Comment: I liked this too. This ensures that I select only such data that matches the attribute name. I am incorporating this into my query.